# How can I get message from an Ethereum transaction?

Tags: web3js, web3.py, message

I send a message from contract to an EOA by this Solidity code:

```
function sendByte(address EOA, bytes memory byteData) external{
        EOA.call("0x416c6972657a61204b69616b6f6a6f757269");
    }
```

Now, How can I see/get the sent message from the generated transaction? Is there a method of web3js or web3py for doing that?

This is the transaction that Truffle console provides:

```
{
  tx: '0x5d07278838b93ba5e2eb12e12e5bf20353ed976b5cd43c935d38dd2b147d79d3',
  receipt: {
    transactionHash: '0x5d07278838b93ba5e2eb12e12e5bf20353ed976b5cd43c935d38dd2b147d79d3',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0x156851759ad78d1b4f94adfdd157c2f1c75cec450e75fa5fa72899cc9abcc2c0',
    blockNumber: 33,
    from: '0xcf247b4a6313aacdb23c7627482d4902d832ef3c',
    to: '0x489a7bb654752b1a7296339019b9ff6b7759fe1b',
    gasUsed: 23453,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 23453,
    contractAddress: null,
    logs: [],
    status: true,
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    rawLogs: []
  },
  logs: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can get the message by emitting an event and looking at the "logs["data"]" field in the transaction receipt (e.g. from truffle console) in your question.

```
contract Test {
    event Message(address indexed receiver, bytes data);
    function sendByte(address EOA, bytes memory byteData) external{
        emit Message(EOA, byteData);
        EOA.call(byteData);
    }
}
```

As mentioned in my other answer, the way you call like this wont affect the EOA address, it only has some effect on your own contract (e.g. emitting event logs).

Comment: So, There is no way to get message by `.call()`, yes? So why should we use `.call(<message>)`?

Comment: we dont need to use .call(message). Depends on your application (I guess you want to implement some messaging app between EOA address ? It should be done with a smart contract but more complex than this.